# adding email domain name verification to a website

Tags: smtp

I want to add email verification for the sign up page for my webpage. I want more then just regular expression verifying to check if the email is in the correct format.

What is the correct method / how do i go by implementing some sort of check to see if domain names are valid domain names?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024819/how-do-i-check-if-an-email-address-is-valid-without-sending-anything-to-it

Answer (score 0):

I have a  function that connects to the mail server and checks the email ttps://github.com/hbattat/verifyEmail