# Is there any way to check if an email will be bounced back through php?

Tags: php, email, email-bounces

I've done my research and everything talks about handling the bounce based on the returned email, but my question is, is it possible to check if an email will be bounced back without going through the bounced back email?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if email exist online using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261987/how-to-check-if-email-exist-online-using-php)

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024819/how-do-i-check-if-an-email-address-is-valid-without-sending-anything-to-it

Answer (score 1):

No, not directly. Unless an email is immediately rejected by the SMTP server that PHP is talking to (e.g. your local `sendmail` install), PHP will assume the email is on its way. If the email is later bounced back by some other mail server (e.g. no such user at the receiving end, mailbox full, etc..), that bounce is a completely SEPARATE email going to the `From:` in your original email.

You can connect that mailbox with PHP, e.g. a `|php somescript.php` rule in a `.forward` file, so that any email coming into that address gets piped into a PHP script, but that'll be a completely separate script, in no way related to the script that sent the original email in the first place.

Comment: If I were to set the reply to and reply path to some email completely, would that be still considered a bounce back to the server?