# Non-intrusive email verification

Tags: email

My company have a website on which, at some point, users are asked to register.
Until a few weeks ago, we used to verify the mail adress by sending an email.
The user had to log into their mail account and click on a link in order to validate their account.
Problem is, we had many users having difficulties (email not received...) or simply leaving the website at this step. Moreover, our support team had to deal with many call about those difficulties.
We decided to remove this verification and it had many positive effects, the first being less ticket for our support team.

However from this point, we had many "fake" emails and I would like to know, what can I do to limit those fake emails without the verification described above? Is there any non-intrusive methods to verify an email adress ?
An exemple of (probably) fake email is hyuiuyhajsdv@gmail.com

Here are what we're already doing to prevent fake emails :

- We're using PHP [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) to validate the format

  - I know it's [not perfect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php#112492) but we didn't found anything better
- We're doing a DNS verification of the domain name (with [gethostbyname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php))

  - This prevents something like superemail@test1245.com
- Finally, we're checking if the domains name match a disposable email service.

Note: we don't have any problem with bots creating fake accounts, so a captcha won't help.

Comment: SMTP had a VRFY command to support this, but it has been abused so much by spammers trying to seek out spam targets that almost everyplace has it disabled.   The spammers have poisoned the well for automated email verification.

Comment: Probably a better workaround is to support additional authentication methods, i.e. allow users to register using their Facebook, Twitter etc credentials, and keep the email with a clickable link for those who prefer that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024819/how-do-i-check-if-an-email-address-is-valid-without-sending-anything-to-it

Comment: @tripleee we already have facebook, twitter and google+ authentication implemented.